# Ошибка "Непредвиденное появление \Java\jre6\jre"

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, websphere

Добрый день, пытаюсь запустить WebSphere, но ничего не выходит. Когда пытаюсь запустить через ярлык, то ничего не понятно, консоль быстро закрывается. Решил запустить батник через консоль из папки bin. Возникает ошибка:

> непредвиденное появление: \Java\jre6\jre

Пробовал разные версии Java ошибка одна и та же. В переменной `JAVA_HOME` указан путь `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6`, а в переменной `PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6`.

Из-за чего данная ошибка возникает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще то `JAVA_HOME` должна указывать не на JRE, а на JDK, типа:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02
```

Comment: да, спасибо за ответ, я уже разобрался.